# session checking not performing as wanted

Tags: php, session

I have an include to check if a session is active on all pages requiring to be logged in to access. 
My login page works, I can access the page and it displays they username from the session on the logged in page but when I log out and try to access the logged in page with the url it lets me back in when it should not.

Here is the security include at the top of each logged in page

```
 <?php

 session_start();

 include('includes/dbconx.php'); //connects to database
 $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user']; //assigns session variable to local variable

 $ses_sql=mysqli_query($con, "select uname from login where uname='$user_check'"); //gets username from database

 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

 $login_session=$row['uname']; //assigns username fromdbase to local variable

 echo $login_session; //echo for testing
 echo $user_check; //echo for testing

 if( $login_session === $user_check) //compares session variable to assigned variable from dbase
 {
  header("loacation: adminPage.php"); //if they match redirect to admin logged in page
 }
 else{ 
 header("location: adminLogin.php"); //else redirect back to login
  }  

 ?>
```

also here is the logout page

```
 <?php
 session_start(); //starts session
 unset($_SESSION["login_user"]);  //unsets session
 header("Location: index.php"); //redirects to home page/
 ?>
```

Comment: What about using `session_destroy()` or even expiring the session cookie ?

Comment: The session is removed fine upon logout, its the fact that once the session is removed i can still access the logged in page via url thats stumping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do below changes in your code:-

**On each page leaving login page :-**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["login_user"])){
   // rest of your complete code including security
}else{
  //redirect to login page or any other page where you want.
}
?>
```

In logout page:-

```
<?php
 session_start(); //starts session
 session_destroy();  //destroy session
 header("Location: index.php"); //redirects to home page/
 ?>
```

Comment: so i replace the whole of my security code with that and add in redirects?

Comment: Means add this condition on top of your each page leaving login.php page.

Comment: Glad to help you. :):):)

Comment: `Thats one way of doing it!`. Sorry but i didn't get this point.